# styled radio works on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, radio-button

I'm using this style to style radio buttons it works fine on firefox but not on chrome. The alert works after clicking the radio but the style doesn't change

http://jsfiddle.net/c2veopa3/2/

```
.example{
margin-bottom : 1.5em;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
width   : 28px;
margin  : 0;
padding : 0;
opacity : 0;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -28px;
  padding-left : 28px;
  background   : url('http://mawk3y.net/cards/checks.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  line-height  : 24px;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label{
background-position : 0 -48px;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `:not(old)` code?  It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work everywhere like this ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/c2veopa3/5/

```
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label:before{
  content: '';
  width: 24px;
  height:24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url('http://mawk3y.net/cards/checks.png') no-repeat; 
  background-position: 0 0;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before{
  background-position : 0 -48px;
}
```

Comment: And yet it doesn't (in Chrome)